# Multithreading : Multiple Process or Single Process

Tags: java, multithreading

I am currently going through this book on OCA java by Kathy Sierra . I came across this line

> Multithreaded Java provides built-in language features and APIs that
>   allow programs to use many operating-system processes (hence, many
>   “cores”) at the same time.

I believe this is conceptually misleading as Java or JVM process is a single process which can have multiple threads with shareable run time memory areas which runs on a single core. So multithreading should be

> "Consuming the idle time of CPU while we wait for some i/o"

and not

> "Running on multiple cores"

.

Do you agree with this ?

Comment: A java program is - for all what i know - always one process. To have multiple processes, one needs to start mutliple JVMs and interconnect them (which is absolutely possible) --- *"multiple threads with shareable run time memory areas which runs on a single core*" - that would be concurrent execution. Every parallel execution is also a concurrent execution, but in a parallel execution, you need more than one core so two threads can run simulttainously, i.e. making progress at the same point in time.

Answer (score 3):

**No**. The JVM is quite capable of utilizing multiple cores with a single process; in ***modern*** implementations it uses native threads. However, if you were restricting your question to [green threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads#Green_threads_in_the_Java_virtual_machine) you would be correct. But that is *ancient* Java technology (circa [Java 1.1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3461/6jck06gqe/index.html)).